# Add the last nonNA value of a row into a new column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
column1 column2 column3
 NA       NA      NA
 0        NA      NA
 0        1       NA
 0        1       2
```

and I would like to keep the last non-NA value of each row and add it in a new column.

This would be the desired output:

```
column4
  NA
  0
  1
  2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `max.col` with `ties.method = "last"`

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df), ties.method = "last"))]
#[1] NA  0  1  2
```

Explanation :

The logic is to create a row/column index to subset values from `df`.

`max.col` returns the column number for each row where the last non-NA value is present. This is the column index. In case there is no non-NA value it returns the 1st column number.

```
max.col(!is.na(df), ties.method = "last")
#[1] 3 1 2 3
```

We generate row index using `1:nrow(df)`, `cbind` them to create matrix which we use to subset the dataframe (`df`).

Comment: Thank you Ronak, your answer is pretty neat and clear

Answer (score 0):

If your values are increasing as per your example, you can use `pmax`, i.e.

```
do.call(pmax, c(df, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] NA  0  1  2
```

Comment: what if in the last row you had 0, 2, 1? This will not give the desired output

Comment: @Onyambu I am aware. That is why I started my answer with the statement: *If your values are increasing*...